# how can we achive dynamic sorting using jpa specification?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, specifications, columnsorting

```
SELECT r.restaurant_id
    FROM restaurant r
    INNER JOIN location ln
    ON r.location_id = ln.location_id
    ORDER BY r.name, ln.name
```

I am able to predicate the above query using JPA specification. But facing issues with the order by.
I am passing value using Map.
Using `searchfilter` I am feting the value, `searchFIlter.get("sort")`---here I have to add the combination for order by.

Sorting will be based on a single parameter, multiple parameters. Whatever user will pass.

How can we achieve this?

```
public List<restaant> findByCriteria(Map<String,String> searchFilter){

            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<restarant> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                if(searchFilter.get("restarant")!=null) {
                    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("restarantName"), employeeName)));
                }

                query.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.get("sort")));           // how to make it  dynamic??Since root.get will not accept joined column...Is there any way to sort based on User requirement may be single sort may be multiple sort...may be from different table?
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }



        });
    }
```

PS: Code is just to give an idea.Not an actual one. For me, my all logic is working except order by just need some good ideas for order by.
Even I have tried using `Sort.by("sort")`;Its not useful.

Comment: With pure Criteria API, then there's no way of making it fully 'dynamic'. Assuming you're using Spring Data, you can try `findAll(Specification, Sort)` combined with `JpaSort.unsafe()`. I suggest you ask yourself whether 'Whatever user will pass' is a sound requirement, though. There's only a limited set of inputs that make sense, and you're exposing the user to potentially unpredictable results

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'may be from different table'? Surely, if sorting is done based on a joined table property, it's not just the `ORDER BY` clause that needs to change?